# How to Pass query parameters from AppsFlyer link to Deep Links/Universal Links

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, appsflyer

I have a component which requires users to input a parameter e.g. their phone numbers. The deep link and universal link inside my apps can accept the parameter e.g. `applinks:www.mywebsite.com/profiles?phone=<Phone Number>`.

In order to serve both Android and iOS, I have to create a link in AppsFlyer. But I can't see any dynamic parameter in AppsFlyer to accept undefined values in a field. What I would like to have is something like `https://secret.onelink.me/profiles?phone=<Phone Number>` so that Phone Number can be passed to my deep link. What should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

AppsFlyer OneLink can pass dynamic parameters through what is called `custom parameters`. The custom parameters can be defined in AppsFlyer's OneLink dashboard, or in OneLink API.
In [this doc](https://dev.appsflyer.com/docs/deep-linking-existing-app-users-to-specific-content) you will find more information.

Comment: For dynamic parameters, what you can do is to predefine values of the parameters. If the values are wide ranged, e.g. phone numbers, how can I set it up?

Comment: You can add the phone number as a query parameter to AppsFlyer link. e.g. `https://secret.onelink.me/profiles?phone=<Phone Number>`. I will show up as a custom parameter.